# The connection was not closed the connection current state is open

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

Hye... I currently doing my final year project using vb.net and i got this error. Im tryin' to fix the error but still not succeed. I use ms access for database in my project. I try to put con.Open() before the 'dt' statement and con.Close() after the 'cboProduct.Select' but the result is the same. Really appreciate your helps. Thanks :)

```
'GLOBAL DECLARATIONS
Dim conString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Acer User\Documents\MAKLUMAT IVENTORI.accdb"
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conString)
Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet

Private Sub RefreshData()
    dt = New DataTable
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM product WHERE lab_kod='66'", con)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    labelID.Text = getAutoID()
    lblLabCode.Text = "66"
    cboProduct.Select()

    Dim v_SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM kategori_product"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(v_SQL, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim v_dataReader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim v_dataTable As New DataTable
    v_dataTable.Columns.Add("product_kod", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    If v_dataReader.HasRows Then
        While v_dataReader.Read
            v_dataTable.Rows.Add(v_dataReader.GetString(0))
        End While
        cboProduct.DataSource = v_dataTable
    End If

    cboProduct.DisplayMember = "product_kod"
    cboProduct.ValueMember = "product_kod"
    v_dataReader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `getAutoID()` do? Is it using the same global connection?

Comment: it used for auto number. so user do not need to put number into ID label. Yup. using the same global connection..

Comment: Then I suspect that is leaving the connection open. If so, close it before exiting `getAutoID`.

Comment: If you have code creating an AutoIncrementing ID, it is not an auto ID at all and will likely fail eventually. Auto numbering is the job of the DB

Comment: I just have to put this code 'If (con.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then con.Close' after the cboProduct.Select().... haha.. programming is quite (not quite i think but really really really) challenging. by the way, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't store short-lived objects, such as database connections, as global variables.
2. In fact, don't use global variables, ever, at all.
   <sub>(though I note that assuming this is a `Class` and not a `Module` those are actually **class fields**, not **globals**, but you're still misusing them)</sub>
3. Your `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill` call requires the connection to be open, but you call `.Fill(dt)` before calling `con.Open()`
4. Use `Using` (`using()` in C#) blocks to ensure your database connection is always closed, even in the event of failure.

Comment: sometimes class level variables are appropriate which is why there is the Dispose pattern. Data adapters will open the connection themselves if it is not open.

Comment: Plus one for mentioning the using statement. All objects that implement IDisposable, or at least the ones that you intend to dispose of when the function is complete, should be instantiated via the Using blocks.

Comment: I want to highlight the point that @Crowcoder mentioned as it is a common misconception. The `Fill()` method will open and then close the connection, it doesn't need to be manually Open'd. [Quote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t(v=vs.110).aspx): "The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open."

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) I just found the solution for my error.